# What syntax highlighting should I use for a Nagios configuration file?

Tags: mac, plugins, textmate

What syntax highlighting should I use with nagios configuration files? Textmate has a lot of options for syntax highlighting but I can't find one that works.

[image]

I've tried using the Apache2 syntax, among others, and I just thing there must be something better for this type of configuration file syntax.

[image: Screen Shot 2012-08-28 at 6.15.08 PM]

I didn't find anything good while googling.